# Listing the content of an array in alphabetical order

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array, with some names (String) in it.

1.) I want to list these names in the array in alphabetical order.
2.) Later i will add some more names to this array, so it had to get appended to this array.

How can i do this programatically ?

note: i don't have any code to demonstrate my working so far. i just have an array created.

**EDIT**

If my array declaration is ;

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"C",@"B", @"M",nil];
```

how can i sort this ?

Comment: Try reading the docs before asking a question.

Comment: Your "array declaration" is invalid code. Please post your real code and show what you've tried to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really try getting used to looking at documentation - once you get the hang of it you can figure things out pretty quickly

The docs for [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) give you the exact way to sort an array:

```
NSArray *array       = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"C", @"B", @"M", nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

---

Now considering you are wanting to add objects later you will most likely use an `NSMutableArray` the docs for [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) show the method:

```
- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
```

Therefore you could use

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"c", @"a", @"b", nil];
[myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

which will sort your array in place resulting in

```
2012-01-10 17:47:11.477 Untitled[11904:707] (
    a,
    b,
    c
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you need:

```
NSArray * sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Of course, some people might ask why you didn't search the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) for "sort array" before asking the question. Not me though. I'm happy to take the points!

Answer (score 1):

This requires that you sort the Array (and you would need to do after new values get added to).  This is pretty simple to do:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This example would be case insensitive - but you could do case sensitive as well.

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look. How do i modify your code to the edited part of my question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to append later, then you should use the mutable type of either `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. If the array contains only names with no other data associated, then the easiest is to use an `NSMutableArray` to store them.

To alphabetize, you can use the `NSArray` method `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` together with `@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)`. This does all the work for you as efficiently as possible.